# How to parse table using Pandas html function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse table located [here](https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/years/2017-standings.html). Using below code, but It is returning multilevel index.

```
url1='aboveurl.htm'

df1=pd.read_html(url1)
df1=df1[0]
```

Comment: which level is the preffered col name?

Comment: 2nd level wich includes rank, W,L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=df[0]
df.columns=df.columns.droplevel()
```

This will remove the multiindex as you preferred.

```
print(df.head())
  Rk                School            Conf   W  L   Pct  W  L   Pct   Off  \
0  1               Clemson  ACC (Atlantic)  12  2  .857  7  1  .875  33.3   
1  2  North Carolina State  ACC (Atlantic)   9  4  .692  6  2  .750  32.2   
2  3            Louisville  ACC (Atlantic)   8  5  .615  4  4  .500  38.1   
3  4           Wake Forest  ACC (Atlantic)   8  5  .615  4  4  .500  35.3   
4  5        Boston College  ACC (Atlantic)   7  6  .538  4  4  .500  25.7   

    Def    SRS   SOS AP Pre AP High AP Rank Notes  
0  13.6  20.62  6.84      5       1       4   NaN  
1  25.2  12.17  5.55    NaN      14      23   NaN  
2  27.4   9.67  3.75     16      14     NaN   NaN  
3  28.3  11.42  6.03    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN  
4  22.8   9.39  7.08    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you , Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No Problem. :) Cheers..!!

Comment: Is there a way to prase only first W,L and PCT wich is under Overall column ?

Comment: @Data_is_Power not sure since format is bad in the Multiindex. :( before `df.columns.droplevel()` if you`print(df.columns.tolist())` you see see bad spaces

Comment: No Worries. I renamed the columns and took care of it

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse only specific columns, `read_html` cannot be used (as far as I know) and one possible alternative approach is to use `beautifulsoup` and scrape row-by-row and column-by-column.

Here's the details

Imports

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Get the soup for the page

```
url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/years/2017-standings.html"
source = result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
```

Extract all rows from the table with `id=standings`

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'standings'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Get the first 6 column names with `th` (which comes from the second row, in order to avoid the row with `Overall`)

```
heads = table_rows[1].find_all('th')[:6]
col_names = [h.text for h in heads]
```

Loop over all rows and extract the fields (using `td`) `School`, `Conf`, `W`, `L`, `Pct` (corresponding to column indexes 0,1,2,3,4, skipped `Rk` which falls under `th` and not `td`) and place them in a nested list, manually inserting the sixth column `Rk` into each sublist for each iteration of the loop

```
standing_rows = []
rank = 1
for tr in table_rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td')
    if cols:
        row = [tr.text for tr in cols[1:6]]
        standing_rows.append([rank]+row)
        rank += 1
```

Finally, put nested list into a Pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(standing_rows, columns=col_names)
```

Here are the first 5 rows

```
df.head()
      Rk                School             Conf   W   L    Pct
0      1               Clemson   ACC (Atlantic)  12   2   .857
1      2  North Carolina State   ACC (Atlantic)   9   4   .692
2      3            Louisville   ACC (Atlantic)   8   5   .615
3      4           Wake Forest   ACC (Atlantic)   8   5   .615
4      5        Boston College   ACC (Atlantic)   7   6   .538
```

and the last 5 rows (not showing the column names)

```
df.tail()
125  126             Louisiana         Sun Belt   5   7   .417
126  127      Louisiana-Monroe         Sun Belt   4   8   .333
127  128                 Idaho         Sun Belt   4   8   .333
128  129         South Alabama         Sun Belt   4   8   .333
129  130           Texas State         Sun Belt   2  10   .167
```